# Erro ao tentar instalar o Router Flux

Tags: javascript, mobile, react, react-native

Me deparei com um erro bem chato ao tentar instalar o Router Flux na pasta do meu app6 alguma sugestão:

Observação: já instalei duas bibliotecas:

> npm install --save eslint-config-rallycoding npm install --save
>
> react-native-router-flux

**codigo: index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Principal from './src/components/Principal';
import SobreJogo from './src/components/SobreJogo';
import OutrosJogos from './src/components/OutrosJogos';

export default class app extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
        <Scene key='principal' component={Principal} initil title="Cara ou coroa" />
        <Scene key='sobrejogo' component={SobreJogo} title="Sobre o Jogo" />
        <Scene key='outrosjogos' component={OutrosJogos} title="Outros Jogos" />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

**PRINCIPAL**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const logo = require('../imgs/logo.png');
const btnJogar = require('../imgs/botao_jogar.png');
const btnSobreJogo = require('../imgs/sobre_jogo.png');
const btnOutrosJogos = require('../imgs/outros_jogos.png');

export default class Principal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cenaPrincipal}>

        <View style={styles.apresentacaoJogo}>
          <Image source={logo} />
          <Image source={btnJogar} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.rodape}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => { Actions.sobrejogo(); }}
          >
            <Image source={btnSobreJogo} />
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => { Actions.outrosjogos(); }}
          >
            <Image source={btnOutrosJogos} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cenaPrincipal: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#61BD8C'
  },
  apresentacaoJogo: {
    flex: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  rodape: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```

**CODIGO SOBRE JOGO**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class SobreJogo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#61BD8C' }}>
                Aqui podem ser apresentadas informações sobre o jogo
            </Text>
        );
    }
}
```

**CODIGO OutrosJogos**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class OutrosJogos extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#61BD8C' }}>
                Aqui podem ser apresentadas informações sobre outros jogos do desenvolvedor
            </Text>
        );
    }
}
```

**BAIXAR CODIGO NO** [GITHUB](https://github.com/alexjosesilva/Curso-React-Native/tree/master/App6)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para mim o erro não parece ter haver com o roteador. Já tentou eliminar partes do código uma por uma até encontrar a parte que dá problema? Também parece ter um erro de JSON. Você está usando isso em algum lugar? E só uma dica, você deve usar `--save-dev` para o `eslint-config-rallycoding`, porquê o mesmo não é necessário para produção, somente desenvolvimento ("DEVelopment").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é um problema com a última versão do Router Flux. Desinstale e use a versão react-native-router-flux@3.38.0  até eles consertarem.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não é um erro da lib.

A nova versão do router-flux modificou um pouco a estrutura para montar o sistema de rotas dele.

A boa notícia é que é bem tranquilo resolver esse problema.

Basta encapsular os componentes Scene dentro de uma outra Scene sem o atributo component, vide exemplo abaixo:

```
<Router>    
     <Scene key='app'>
          <Scene key='principal' component={Principal} title='Cara ou Coroa?' titleStyle={styles.nav} />
          <Scene key='sobrejogo' component={SobreJogo} title='Sobre o Jogo' titleStyle={styles.nav} />
         <Scene key='outrosjogos' component={OutrosJogos} title='Outros Jogos' titleStyle={styles.nav} />    
         <Scene key='resultado' component={Resultado} title='Resultado' titleStyle={styles.nav} />
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Att,

Júlio Falbo